# R and G wire jumpered and G is not connected to thermostat

Tags: hvac, wire

I have a Trane XV90 furnace and XL14i AC. The thermostat is old and I want to install a Honeywell Wifi one. Today I just checked the wires and found on the control board R and G are jumpered and the G is not actually connected to the thermostat. So my question is when I install the new thermostat, should I keep the G wire as is or rewire and connect it? Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the brand of furnace/AC - not everybody is that familiar.

Comment: "Jumpered", not "shorted". A short-circuit is something else.

Comment: Thanks Freeman and Isherwood. I'm curious should I remove the jumper between R and G and connect the G wire to the new thermostat? I guess if I just leave it as is and did not connect G it should still function and will not break the board, is that right? Thanks.

Comment: Well that’s a better way to ask compared to i don’t know how it works is taking it out a good idea.  You could try an experiment and remove the red/green jumper try turning the system on and see if the fan comes on if it will you may not need it if it won’t come on you may need it. Not all controll boards make sense. R jumpered to g usually turns the fan on btw but not always. Going to a new control I usually take a photo of the original connections then hook up the new control with the color code if everything works great if not backtrack and figure what jumpers need to be there.